# core generated accessors not generated correctly

Tags: ios, core-data, accessor

I am having errors trying to run this app with core data.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "ingredient"; desired type = NSSet; given type = Ingredient;

I see that the core-generated accessors addIngredient: and removeIngredient: both take an NSSet as a parameter, so I tried changing that to Ingredient, but that didn't help.  I suspect that although I change the parameter in the header, there is something going on in implementation that I can't see?  Suggestions?

Recipe.h

```
@class IngredientList;

@interface Recipe : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * recipeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IngredientList *ingredientList;

@end
```

IngredientList.h

```
@class Ingredient, Recipe;

@interface IngredientList : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) Recipe *recipe;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *ingredient;
@end

@interface IngredientList (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addIngredientObject:(Ingredient *)value;
- (void)removeIngredientObject:(Ingredient *)value;
- (void)addIngredient:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeIngredient:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Ingredient.h

```
@class IngredientList;

@interface Ingredient : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ingredientName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IngredientList *ingredientList;

@end
```

Comment: Did the answer help? Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly then `ingredient` is a to-many relationship from `IngredientList` 
to `Ingredient`. (*Remark:* A better name would be the plural form `ingredients`.)

Then `addIngredientObject:`, not `addIngredient:` is the method to add an ingredient
to a list:

```
IngredientList *aList = ...;
Ingredient *anIngredient = ...;
[aList addIngredientObject:anIngredient];
```

Alternatively, you can set the inverse relationship:

```
anIngredient.ingredientList = aList;
```

The method `addIngredient:`, which takes an `NSSet` as argument, is used to add
an entire set of objects to the relationship in one step.

The Core Data accessor methods are generated dynamically at runtime,
therefore you cannot just change the generated .h or .m file.
You should always let Xcode re-generate the files if the model has been changed.